# How to restrict user to view directory If subDomain Url format is wrong

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

Currently, I am redirecting all my subdomains to a particular folder using the .htaccess file. Below I have mentioned my .htaccess file code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirection of subDomain to v1 subdirectory
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.abc\.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v1/$1 [END,NE,R=permanent]
</IfModule>
```

Problem is If anyone enters wrong subdomain url like 123.122.abc.com, then this also redirects to /v1 directory. I want only one level subdomains.

Comment: A subdomain like `123.122.abc.com` does not match the rule you've posted. (Specifically, the regex `^[^.]+\.abc\.com$` does not match `123.122.abc.com`.) Are you really using Apache 1.3?!

Comment: @MrWhite I am using httpd in Linux ec2 instance

Comment: Well, like I say, the rule above does not redirect as you've stated. But also, unless you have other directives that prevent it, this rule would result in a redirect-loop for "correct" subdomains! (Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/v1` subdirectory?) So, the problem would seem to be "somewhere else", or you are perhaps seeing a cached redirect?

Comment: The answer is simple, do not use .htaccess, define the appropiate virtualhosts with their own documentroot.